# trying to get the date range members

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to get the member details those who are notpaid by the given date range like this ((givendate+8 ,givendate+30) like this
I want the details like this the memebrs who are are not paid between these dates(((givendate+8 ,givendate+30))

like this if givendate is (1-09-2008) i want the date range like this (08-09-2008 ,30-09-2008)

i have done

```
WHERE  DATE_ADD(memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue,DATE_DIFF((ADDDATE(memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue, 8)),(ADDDATE(memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue,30))) )< NOW()
```

NOTE givendate = memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue taking into account today date

but it was giving error

```
    Error Code: 1064
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATEDIFF((ADDDATE(memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue, 8)),(ADDDATE(memberpays' at line 18
```

would any one pls give any idea about this

Comment: you are getting error `'DATEDIFF((ADDDATE(memberpaysched......`, and in question you have posted query like `DATE_DIFF((ADDDATE(memberpaysched`.. check your exicuted query ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this instead:

```
WHERE 
  memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue BETWEEN 
    CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 DAY 
    AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: how can we get the expression like this (> givendate+30)

Comment: `memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue > '2011-08-08' + INTERVAL 30 DAY`

Comment: sorrymemberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue > '2011-08-08' + INTERVAL 30 DAY  not working but this is the range between 8 to 30 i want more than 30(nearly after 30 days) how can we get this taking into account today date....

Answer (score 1):

```
...
where
memberPaySched_dateDue
between '2008-09-01' + interval 7 day and '2008-09-01' + interval 29 day
```

Comment: how can we get the expression like this (> givendate+30)

Comment: date_field > givendate + interval 30 day

Comment: sorry >givendate +30 not working but this is the range between 8 to 30 i want more than 30(nearly after 30 days) how can we get this taking into account today date....

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and as close to how you would express it in English as possible:

```
WHERE memberPaySched_dateDue between ADDDATE(NOW(), 8) and ADDDATE(NOW(), 30)
```

or if you have a particular date instead of `now()`:

```
WHERE memberPaySched_dateDue between ADDDATE('2011-09-01', 8) and ADDDATE('2011-09-01', 30)
```

Note that since the two between range values are constant during execution, this will be performant (unlike your code which forced a calculation every row)

Comment: how can we get the expression like this (> givendate+30)

Comment: thanq but this is the range between 8 to 30 i want more than 30(nearly after 30 days)    how can we get this taking into account today date.....